# Reading the status (Checked/Unchecked) of a CheckBoxList checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am currently using a databound CheckBoxList and I need to identify the status of what checkbox was checked, and unchecked, etc. Basically when a user presses a checkbox it autopostbacks, I read some data from the database, and have a running Session with totals. What I need is when a checkbox is unchecked to identify this change, also make a database call, and substract the amount that product is supposed to cost. Or maybe just read every checkbox everytime a checkbox is checked/unchecked but I'd think that's less optimal.

```
  protected void CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        decimal CompraTotal = 0;
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(GlobalVars.mysql);
        connection.Open();

        MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = "QUERY";
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?GUID", Session["GUID"]);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Name", CheckBoxList1.SelectedValue);
        MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        decimal Price = 0;
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Price = Convert.ToDecimal(reader["Price"]);
        }


        Total = Convert.ToDecimal(Session["Total"]);
        Total = Total + Price;
        Session["Total"] = Total;

    }
```

I just need to identify what checkbox was unchecked and run a similar query to substract from the total. THanks for any help :)

EDIT: Updated code (made some adjustments to variables and stuff as well):

```
            if (Session["previouslySelected"] != null && Session["previouslySelected"].ToString() != "-1")
        {
            decimal CompraTotal2 = 0;
            MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(GlobalVars.mysql);
            connection.Open();

            MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "QUERY";
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?GUID", Session["GUID"]);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Nombre", CheckBoxList1.SelectedValue);
            MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            decimal Precio = 0;
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                // reader.GetString(0);
                Precio = Convert.ToDecimal(reader["Precio"]);

            }


            CompraTotal2 = Convert.ToDecimal(Session["CompraTotal"]);
            CompraTotal2 = Precio - CompraTotal2;
            Session["CompraTotal"] = CompraTotal2;

        }

        if (CheckBoxList1.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            decimal CompraTotal = 0;
            MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(GlobalVars.mysql);
            connection.Open();

            MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "QUERY";
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?GUID", Session["GUID"]);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Nombre", CheckBoxList1.SelectedValue);
            MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            decimal Precio = 0;
            int i = 0;
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                // reader.GetString(0);
                Precio = Convert.ToDecimal(reader["Precio"]);

            }


            CompraTotal = Convert.ToDecimal(Session["CompraTotal"]);
            CompraTotal = CompraTotal + Precio;
            Session["CompraTotal"] = CompraTotal;
        }

        Session["previouslySelected"] = CheckBoxList1.SelectedIndex;
        Label3.Text = Convert.ToString(Session["CompraTotal"]);


        }
```

The problem I am facing know is that the first part of the code also executes at the same time as the other one, giving me bad values. I have two items databound to my CheckList, I have Option 1 and Option 2. I concatenated the values for the text since there are prices, so what I am displaying is Option 1  $1.00   Option 2 $0.50. With the query I get a specific GUID and since the name is unique I look up the Price value. If the checkbox was unchecked it should check for that value, then subtract from the current total. If the checkbox was checked it should then look for that value and add it.

FINAL FIXED CODE FOR THOSE WHO ARE IN THE SAME SITUATION

```
  for (int i = 0; i < CheckBoxList1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Selected)
            {
                values += CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Value + ",";

               \\COMMANDS EXECUTE HERE

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (Session["previouslySelected"] != null && Session["previouslySelected"].ToString() != "-1")
        {
            decimal CompraTotal2 = 0;
            MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(GlobalVars.mysql);
            connection.Open();

        MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = "QUERY";
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?GUID", Session["GUID"]);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Nombre", Session["previouslySelected"].ToString());
        MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        decimal Precio = 0;
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // reader.GetString(0);
            Precio = Convert.ToDecimal(reader["Precio"]);

        }


        CompraTotal2 = Convert.ToDecimal(Session["CompraTotal"]);
        CompraTotal2 = Precio - CompraTotal2;
        Session["CompraTotal"] = CompraTotal2;

    }

    if (CheckBoxList1.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        decimal CompraTotal = 0;
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(GlobalVars.mysql);
        connection.Open();

        MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = "QUERY";
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?GUID", Session["GUID"]);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Nombre", CheckBoxList1.SelectedValue);
        MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        decimal Precio = 0;
        int i = 0;
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // reader.GetString(0);
            Precio = Convert.ToDecimal(reader["Precio"]);

        }


        CompraTotal = Convert.ToDecimal(Session["CompraTotal"]);
        CompraTotal = CompraTotal + Precio;
        Session["CompraTotal"] = CompraTotal;
    }

    Session["previouslySelected"] = CheckBoxList1.SelectedIndex;
    Label3.Text = Convert.ToString(Session["CompraTotal"]);


    }
```

Comment: Adjusted the code sightly as the IDE threw me a error at if(CheckBoxList1.SelectedIndex) and changed that part to a "Else". Didn't seem to work, though I see where you are coming from.  I wish this was a simble "Checkbox1.Checked = false" thing but its giving me more trouble than I bargained for :P

Comment: Tried it. Still has no effect. Grrgh. Trying with different combinations of stuff and still no go. *sigh*

Comment: What's the issue now?  Before it was a syntax error on my side, exactly what happens when you use the code from my answer?  Sorry I couldn't give you the exact code first time around... Update me with what's happening and I'll try my best...

Comment: I added some breakpoints and it seems the program never gets to anything inside the "previouslyselected" brackets and just skips ahead to the next if.

Comment: PreviouslySelected will only be hit on the second run.  So click something in the list, then click something else in the list, then you should see it drop into the right part...

Comment: Nop, it never fires up. Maybe I am doing something wrong? I am using the same exact code as the one you psoted and no go.

Comment: PreviouslySelected  is a private variable and on each postback it will be set to -1. If you want it to persist, you have to save it to viewstate or session.

Comment: I figured (without testing) the ToString was implicit.  I could be wrong, so I changed the code to have a ToString()...

Comment: Hey Vijay. It crashes if I add the (Session["previouslySelected"]ToString() != "-1") line "Object Reference not Found". I can't understand for the sake of me why this is so hard. I also tried a "for each" I found elsewhere to no results. Maybe I should try changing my approach or something.

Comment: And yes I added the . after ToString(). Just in case :P. Thanks a million for the help provided so far though, really appreciated.

Comment: Try it now... Also, once it's working, don't forget to up vote my comments and answer too! :)  I forgot to add in a null check, it's 02:05 in the morning here...

Comment: It seems to be now identifying when something is checked and unchecked but the total values are not giving me a correct amount. Basically inside the "minus" part of the code I have another DataReader code that reads the price then deducts from the current session, yet that doesn't seem to be happening. I'll tinker a bit more, sleep is killing me. Thanks Vijay

Comment: Post your updated code along with comments in the code explaining what you are trying to do (and what is happening).  I'm going to sleep now, but I'll pick this up tomorrow (in around eight hours...).

Comment: Thanks a million Vijay. Posted the updated code and a more clear look at what I want to do. Thanks :)

Comment: I think you were just using the currently selected index still.  I made a small change, try it again... - And feel free to upvote my comments here too, I could do with the points! :)

Comment: SO, I got back to trying the updated code... aaaand... no go. Its definitely registering the unchecks/checks but something ain't right in the way its handling the substract/addition. I'll sit down and try and wrap my head around it, thanks a bunch Vijay :)

Comment: If your project is small and not private, host it somewhere, post your question to SO along with some snippets and we'll get it fixed for you.  But do try to figure it out yourself... It's those hours you spend banging your head against the wall that make you a good programmer... Remembering something is pointless, you will struggle to innovate if it's just handed to you... Anyway, if you do get stuck, we'll be here :)

Comment: Yeah I'll try and crack it down. At least the uncheck/check is registering, what follows is a nice path down... banging my head. Thanks.

Comment: After some head crashing I finally figured it out. I worked it out different at the end Vijay, but your help was really appreciated and I am sure it will help some. Thanks :)